# Why do some iOS Crash Reports have different Binary Images?

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I have a hundred+ crash reports from different users, all crashing at the same line of code. I was doing some statistics on these crash reports, and not all of them have the same Binary Images list.

From what I understand about iOS Crash Reports, the Binary Images show what libraries are loaded by your app. But why should my app produce crash reports with different libraries for different users?

Most of the crashes have standard items such as:

- AVFoundation
- Accelerate
- vImage
- libBLAS.dylib
- libLAPACK.dylib
- libvDSP.dylib
- libvMisc.dylib
- ...

But some different by having some of these items:

- IncomingCallFilter
- IMAVCore
- RawCamera
- Librarian
- Ubiquity
- CoreServicesInternal
- ...

My app doesn't use the camera services or iCloud, so I don't know why those binary images should be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of the operating system may link in different libraries and frameworks when your app launches. Perhaps the frameworks that you do use are dependent on things you don't use, like RawCamera, and so those are loaded even though you don't use them directly in your app.

Check the iOS version and hardware associated with each report.